# Max data per year

Tags: r

```
start.date  spell length  
1987-10-01         34  
1987-10-25         2  
1987-10-30         5  
1987-11-16         78
```

I am trying to find a code that can look at 30 years of data and only keeps the longest spell length of each year. Theoretically, I would have 30 dates and 30 spell lengths in a data frame. Thank you in advance!

End result

```
start.date  spell length  
1987-11-16        78
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `which.max` to find the index of the max value in `"spell length"` column and use that to subset the row of the dataset

```
dat[which.max(dat[[2]]),, drop = FALSE]
```

---

If there are multiple years, then extract the 'year' part as grouping variable to be used in `ave` to create a logical index for subsetting the rows of the dataset

```
grp <- format(as.Date(dat$start.date), "%Y")
i1 <- with(dat, ave(`spell length`, grp, FUN = max) == `spell length`)
dat[i1, , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: It's max by year though, so you need to pull out `lubridate::year(start.date)` or `substr(start.date,1,4)` first